# jQuery Autocomplete - получить список предложений

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

При инициализации autocomplete, ему передается source.

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
  source: availableTags
});
```

Как ПОЛУЧИТЬ это значение? НЕ установить.

Comment: Какое значение? Опишите проблему подробнее

Comment: source. Массив автоподстановки. Предложения, из которых можно выбрать.

Comment: что именно вы хотите получить? список после фильтрации?

Answer (score 3):

```
var source = $( ".selector" ).autocomplete( "option", "source" );
```

Comment: Не работает. Выхлоп такой же, как при использовании $("#autocomplete").

Comment: и всё-таки ответ верный, согласно документации:
http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ .
Проверьте, что значение действительно установлено, когда вы пытаетесь его получить